# How to avoid Python being confuse code after the variable is apply in multiple part?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
FamilyVsWWTotal = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2011-4-3','2011-3-5','2011-4-3','2011-5-7'], 'Country':['USA','CAN','USA','MEX']})
```

So it will have following output:

```
date          Country
2011-4-3      USA
2011-3-5      CAN
2011-4-3      USA
2011-5-7      MEX
```

And then below code is 2 created table 1:

```
 Table1=FamilyVsWWTotal
 Table1['Region']='K'
```

Hence the Table1 will have following output:

```
date          Country   Region
2011-4-3      USA       K
2011-3-5      CAN       K
2011-4-3      USA       K
2011-5-7      MEX       K
```

For the second table which is Table2:

```
Table2=FamilyVsWWTotal
Table2['aveAge']=60
```

Hence Table2 output should be like this:

```
date          Country   aveAge
2011-4-3      USA       60
2011-3-5      CAN       60
2011-4-3      USA       60
2011-5-7      MEX       60
```

But I always face this problem which is the Table2output will be look like this which already mix up the code from the above:

**Table2**

```
date          Country   Region   aveAge
2011-4-3      USA       K        60
2011-3-5      CAN       K        60
2011-4-3      USA       K        60
2011-5-7      MEX       K        60
```

Anyone can give some ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Well asked question with data samples +1

Answer (score 4):

You need [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) for new `DataFrame` object, because else working with same (without copy is not `copied` by value, but creating a new `reference`, so `id` is same):

```
Table1=FamilyVsWWTotal.copy()

print (id(Table1))
243907608
print (id(FamilyVsWWTotal))
193392088
```

```
#crete new object (unlink to original df)
Table1 = FamilyVsWWTotal.copy()
Table2=FamilyVsWWTotal.copy()
Table1['Region'] = 'K'
Table2['aveAge']=60
print (FamilyVsWWTotal)
  Country      date
0     USA  2011-4-3
1     CAN  2011-3-5
2     USA  2011-4-3
3     MEX  2011-5-7

print (Table1)
  Country      date Region
0     USA  2011-4-3      K
1     CAN  2011-3-5      K
2     USA  2011-4-3      K
3     MEX  2011-5-7      K

print (Table2)
  Country      date  aveAge
0     USA  2011-4-3      60
1     CAN  2011-3-5      60
2     USA  2011-4-3      60
3     MEX  2011-5-7      60
```

---

```
#create refernce only
Table1=FamilyVsWWTotal

print (id(Table1))
244095352
print (id(FamilyVsWWTotal))
244095352
```

Still modify original DataFrame `FamilyVsWWTotal`:

```
Table1 = FamilyVsWWTotal
Table2=FamilyVsWWTotal
Table1['Region'] = 'K'
Table2['aveAge']=60
print (FamilyVsWWTotal)
  Country      date Region  aveAge
0     USA  2011-4-3      K      60
1     CAN  2011-3-5      K      60
2     USA  2011-4-3      K      60
3     MEX  2011-5-7      K      60

print (Table1)
  Country      date Region  aveAge
0     USA  2011-4-3      K      60
1     CAN  2011-3-5      K      60
2     USA  2011-4-3      K      60
3     MEX  2011-5-7      K      60

print (Table2)
  Country      date Region  aveAge
0     USA  2011-4-3      K      60
1     CAN  2011-3-5      K      60
2     USA  2011-4-3      K      60
3     MEX  2011-5-7      K      60
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `.assign` returns a new dataframe.

```
In [137]: Table1 = FamilyVsWWTotal.assign(Region='K')

In [138]: Table1
Out[138]:
  Country      date Region
0     USA  2011-4-3      K
1     CAN  2011-3-5      K
2     USA  2011-4-3      K
3     MEX  2011-5-7      K

In [139]: Table2 = FamilyVsWWTotal.assign(aveAge=60)

In [140]: Table2
Out[140]:
  Country      date  aveAge
0     USA  2011-4-3      60
1     CAN  2011-3-5      60
2     USA  2011-4-3      60
3     MEX  2011-5-7      60

In [141]: FamilyVsWWTotal
Out[141]:
  Country      date
0     USA  2011-4-3
1     CAN  2011-3-5
2     USA  2011-4-3
3     MEX  2011-5-7
```

Or, work on `copy`

```
In [142]: Table1 = FamilyVsWWTotal.copy()

In [143]: Table1['Region'] = 'K'

In [144]: Table1
Out[144]:
  Country      date Region
0     USA  2011-4-3      K
1     CAN  2011-3-5      K
2     USA  2011-4-3      K
3     MEX  2011-5-7      K

In [145]: FamilyVsWWTotal
Out[145]:
  Country      date
0     USA  2011-4-3
1     CAN  2011-3-5
2     USA  2011-4-3
3     MEX  2011-5-7
```

Answer (score 2):

Performing `Table1=FamilyVsWWTotal` results in shallow copy. The two variables link to the same DataFrame object in the memory.

You can check this by:

```
print(id(Table1))
print(id(FamilyVsWWTotal))
```

---

If you want two separate DataFrames, where you can do separate calculations, you must perform a deep copy, like this:

```
Table1 = FamilyVsWWTotal.copy(deep=True)
```

As `deep=True` is default with `copy()`, you can just do

```
Table1 = FamilyVsWWTotal.copy()
```

Similarly,

```
Table2 = FamilyVsWWTotal.copy(deep=True)
```

---

Thus, your code should look like this:

```
FamilyVsWWTotal = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2011-4-3','2011-3-5','2011-4-3','2011-5-7'], 'Country':['USA','CAN','USA','MEX']})
Table1=FamilyVsWWTotal.copy()
Table1['Region']='K'
Table2=FamilyVsWWTotal.copy()
Table2['aveAge']=60
```

Answer (score 0):

While others already answered your question, I think knowing the difference between a deep copy and a shallow help would help next time:

[What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)